# GWTP typesafe with @UiHandler for ui elements

Tags: event-handling, gwtp, gwt-platform

Before GWTP, I used aproach like this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                   // doSomething()
            }
        });
```

But  gwtp framework maks me use this aproach:

```
@UiField 
Button button;

@UiHandler("button")
void onButtonClick(ClickEvent e){
    getUiHandlers().buttonClickAction();
}
```

I wonder is there any **TYPESAFE** solution for this?

How to give to `@UiHandler()` type safe value f.e.:

```
@UiHandler(button);
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `@UiHandler` is a GWT UiBinder feature. It has nothing to do with GWTP. If you want to ensure no one changes the type of `ui:field` in the xml file, you can map it with `@UiField` first.

```
@UiField 
Button button;

@UiHandler("button")
void onButtonClick(ClickEvent e){
  getUiHandlers().buttonClickAction();
}
```

This way, in case someone puts ui:field not to a button in ui.xml file - It will fail at compile time. Hope it helped

Comment: I have `@UiField`. I did not put it in post. In Your answer still is string in `@UiHandler`. I am looking for something type safe like `addClickHandler` approach.

Comment: Define type safety then. If you change <b:Button ui:field='button'/> to <g:SimplePanel ui:field='button'/> you will have a compile-time error + IntelliJ has real-time analysis on those, so everything will be in red. Regarding IntelliJ, I believe if you put eventType not supported by "button" - idea will warn you on that one as well.

Comment: So there is no better way?

Comment: You can take the widget.addClickHandler(...) approach as you did it before, though it's less clean. https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8941/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/HandlerDemo.java - take a look, if it works this way for Google, guess it's ok